# Convert UTC to days, hours minutes etc in C

Tags: c, datetime, date, time

I have a a long which has the time in UTC format as a timestamp for some data, now I want to convert it to this format:
month 1-12
Day 1-31 
24 Hour format 0-23
minute 0-59
second 0-59
subsecond nanoseconds 0-999,999,999

now the nanoseconds can obviously be set to 0 as it doesnt need to be that accurate.

What is the best method to do this? I've seen loads of examples but they are confusing and don't seem to work for converting an arbitrary date, they only work for converting the exact time at that moment.

Comment: Any strictly UTC function will return [0, 60] for seconds (60 being a leap second), however, many implementations ignore this. Be aware of whatever implementation you choose does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Note the commented lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[512];
  long stamp = 1287055578;
  struct tm x;
  time_t cstamp = stamp;       /* 1 */
  x = *gmtime(&cstamp);        /* 2 */

  sprintf(buf, "month %d Day %d 24 Hour format %d minute %d second %d "
               "subsecond nanoseconds 0",
               x.tm_mon + 1, x.tm_mday, x.tm_hour, x.tm_min, x.tm_sec);

  printf("%s\n", buf); /* long converted to string */
  return 0;
}
```

1) `gmtime` takes a value of type `time_t*`, so I implicitly convert the `long` to `time_t` and pass that address in the next step

2) `gmtime` returns a pointer to a `struct tm` object. Dereference that pointer and copy the object to my local `x` variable

Instead of `gm_time`, you may want to use `localtime` and have the library functions deal with time zones and daylight saving time issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) header. [asctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/asctime/), [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/), [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/) etc converts time to string.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers everyone, I ended up doing it this way

```
long UTCInSeconds = ...

struct tm * local;
local = localtime(UTCInSeconds);

Month = local->tm_mon + 1;
Day = local->tm_mday;
Year = local->tm_year + 1900;
Hour = local->tm_hour;
Minute = local->tm_min;
Second = local->tm_sec;
```